# To convert google sheet script into an array to run faster

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that when run adds cells together (i.e A1 + A2 and returning the result in A1), there are 2 tables that are each 2 x 17 so currently I have a chunk of code for each cell is there a way to do this via an array? Here is the script I am currently using.

```
function Transfer() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C5").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!B3").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C5").setValue(num1+num2);

var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D5").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!C3").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D5").setValue(num1+num2);


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C6").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!B4").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C6").setValue(num1+num2);

var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D6").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!C4").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D6").setValue(num1+num2);


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C7").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!B5").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C7").setValue(num1+num2);

var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D7").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!C5").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D7").setValue(num1+num2);


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C8").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!B6").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C8").setValue(num1+num2);

var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D8").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!C6").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D8").setValue(num1+num2);


 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C9").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!B7").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C9").setValue(num1+num2);

var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D9").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!C7").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D9").setValue(num1+num2);


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C11").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!B9").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C11").setValue(num1+num2);

var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D11").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!C9").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D11").setValue(num1+num2);


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C12").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!B10").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C12").setValue(num1+num2);

var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D12").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!C10").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D12").setValue(num1+num2);


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C13").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!B11").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C13").setValue(num1+num2);

var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D13").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!C11").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D13").setValue(num1+num2);


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C14").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!B12").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C14").setValue(num1+num2);

var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D14").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!C12").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D14").setValue(num1+num2);


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C15").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!B13").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C15").setValue(num1+num2);

var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D15").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!C13").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D15").setValue(num1+num2);


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C16").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!B14").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C16").setValue(num1+num2);

var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D16").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!C14").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D16").setValue(num1+num2);


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C17").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!B15").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C17").setValue(num1+num2);

var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D17").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!C15").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D17").setValue(num1+num2);


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C18").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!B16").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C18").setValue(num1+num2);

var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D18").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!C16").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D18").setValue(num1+num2);


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C19").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!B17").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C19").setValue(num1+num2);

var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D19").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!C17").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D19").setValue(num1+num2);


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C20").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!B18").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C20").setValue(num1+num2);

var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D20").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!C18").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D20").setValue(num1+num2);


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C21").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!B19").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C21").setValue(num1+num2);

var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D21").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!C19").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D21").setValue(num1+num2);


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C22").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!B20").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!C22").setValue(num1+num2);

var num1 = ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D22").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("2ndTrailer!C20").getValue();
ss.getRange("Monday-Saturday!D22").setValue(num1+num2);

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('2ndTrailer');
sheet.getRange('A2').clearContent();

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Monday-Saturday');
sheet.getRange('A23').setValue('YES');

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us access to a sample of you Spreadsheet, to better understand your problem ?

Comment: You can get the sheet as a 2D array with `getDataRange()` and `getValues()` and then loop through rows and columns, performing the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with arrays and loop :

```
function Transfer() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName('Monday-Saturday');
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName('2ndTrailer');

  var data1 = s1.getRange(5, 3, 18, 2).getValues();
  var data2 = s2.getRange(3, 2, 18, 2).getValues();
  var newData = [];

  for(var i = 0 ; i < data1.length; i++){

    var newValueC = data1[i][0] + data2[i][1];
    var newValueD = data1[i][1] + data2[i][1];

    newData.push([newValueC, newValueD]);

  }

  s1.getRange(5, 3, 18, 2).setValues(newData);

  s2.getRange('A2').clearContent();
  s1.getRange('A23').setValue('YES');

}
```

A bit ugly, but should do the trick.

Edit: Made a few changes, since the range.setValue() method causing problems

Comment: Hi thanks for that but it seems to be functioning incorrectly, for example 'Monday-Saturday' C5 is not adding with 2ndTrailer B3 to give a result back in C5 the 'cages' column in 2ndTrailer seems to be adding to both columns in 'Monday-Saturday' and the final row 'Gift Food' seems to be missed from the script. Here is copy of sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11eclWiYXjC2hTaTJdzK5PeSsfTOm86laEwnmWViuErM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, I've made a few changes on the code, it's should work now (I've tried on a copy of your spreadsheet and it work.